# How to select the nth jQuery object in a jQuery collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="box">
          <div class="a"></div>
          <div class="b"></div>
          <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
          <div class="a"></div>
          <div class="b"></div>
          <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
          <div class="a"></div>
          <div class="b"></div>
          <div class="c"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I execute

```
var rootElement = $('.grid').find('.box');
```

`rootElement` contains a collection of jQuery objects.

How do I access a specific jQuery object in this collection?   I don't want to use .each() since I'm not necessarily going to iterate through the entire collection.

I know this works, but this seems awkward.

```
var index = 1;
$(rootElement.get(index)).find('.a'); /* Use chaining to do more work */
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: You could do `rootElement[n]`

Comment: I tried rootElement[index].find('.a'), and I got a JS error.  rootElement[index] gives me the DOM element, not the jQuery Object.

Comment: yes, it would. However you could use `$(rootElement[n])` to get a jQuery wrapped element, of course.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
var rootElement = $('.grid').find('.box').eq(0);
rootElement.find('.a'); /* Use chaining to do more work */
```

Comment: +1 Although no need to wrap `rootElement` since it's already a jQuery object. :o)